# Обработка ошибки в doInBacground

Tags: android

Есть следующий кусок кода (разбираю json данные)

```
try{
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(source);
    SearchResponse response = gson.fromJson(reader, SearchResponse.class);
    results = response.results;
}
catch (RuntimeException e){
    Log.w("RuntimeException", "RuntimeException");
    e.printStackTrace();
    // ВОТ В ЭТОМ МЕСТЕ
}
```

Вопрос: как мне в указанном месте сообщить пользователю, что нет инета. Т.е. вызвать диалог в этом месте я не могу, так как происходит RuntimeException внутри catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А кто вашему `doInBackground` мешает возвратить null  к примеру. тогда в `onPostExecute`, проверив на null, можно узнать, что что-то пошло не так. Осталось только протащить текст ошибки. Это ещё проще. Заводим себе поле/поля нужного типа и сохраняем там текст ошибки или ее код.

Вот пример из одного с проектов:

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
    private string err = "";
    protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        try {
            int count = urls.length;
            long totalSize = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
                publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
                // Escape early if cancel() is called
                if (isCancelled()) break;
            }
            return totalSize;
        } catch() {
            err = "ups";
            return Null;
        }
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        if (result == Null) {
           showError(err);
           return;
        }
        showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
    }
}
```

Но еще есть событие `onProgressUpdate` - которое можно вызывать регулярно для обновления прогресса. Отсутствие интернета - это тоже этап в прогрессе.

Comment: почему в одном посте 3 раза ошибка в слове Backgroundd?

Comment: я только одну нашел. Видимо Вы видите ошибки и в других словах.
**upd**
нашел две другие - в теме и в Вашем посте:)

Comment: спсибо за хороший полный ответ!